# how to make label visible/invisible?

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have these date and time fields, and I want to set a javascript validation for the time.

If the format is invalid, it should make the label visible, else it should be invisible.

This is the code I have so far.

```
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <span id="startDateLabel">Start date/time: </span>
                        <input id="startDateStr" name="startDateStr" size="8" onchange="if (!formatDate(this,'USA')) {this.value = '';}" />
                        <button id="startDateCalendarTrigger">...</button>
                        <input id="startDateTime" type="text" size="8" name="startTime" value="12:00 AM" onchange="validateHHMM(this.value);"/>
                        <label id="startTimeLabel" visible="false">Time must be entered in the format HH:MM AM/PM</label>
                        <BR>
                        <span id="endDateLabel">End date/time: </span>
                        <input id="endDateStr" name="endDateStr" size="8" onchange="if (!formatDate(this,'USA')) {this.value = '';}" />
                        <button id="endDateCalendarTrigger">...</button>
                        <input id="endDateTime" type="text" size="8" name="endTime" value="12:00 AM" onchange="validateHHMM2(this.value);"/>
                        <label id="endTimeLabel" visible="false">Time must be entered in the format HH:MM AM/PM</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
```

The problem is the label shows up when loaded irrespective of what I set as visible. I tried visibility = "hidden" and it still shows up.

Here is the validation part:

```
    <script>
function validateHHMM(inputField) {
    var isValid = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/.test(inputField.value);

    if (isValid) {
        document.getElementById("startTimeLabel").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("startTimeLabel").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    return isValid;
}
function validateHHMM2(inputField) {
    var isValid = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/.test(inputField.value);

    if (isValid) {
        document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    return isValid;
}
 </script>
```

So, how should I go about this? Google shows up different validation methods but not how to hide/show labels

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are looking for display:

```
document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.display = 'block';
```

**Edit:** You could also easily reuse your validation function.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="startDateLabel">Start date/time: </span>
<input id="startDateStr" name="startDateStr" size="8" onchange="if (!formatDate(this,'USA')) {this.value = '';}" />
<button id="startDateCalendarTrigger">...</button>
<input id="startDateTime" type="text" size="8" name="startTime" value="12:00 AM" onchange="validateHHMM(this.value, 'startTimeLabel');"/>
<label id="startTimeLabel" class="errorMsg">Time must be entered in the format HH:MM AM/PM</label><br />

<span id="endDateLabel">End date/time: </span>
<input id="endDateStr" name="endDateStr" size="8" onchange="if (!formatDate(this,'USA')) {this.value = '';}" />
<button id="endDateCalendarTrigger">...</button>

<input id="endDateTime" type="text" size="8" name="endTime" value="12:00 AM" onchange="validateHHMM(this.value, 'endTimeLabel');"/>
<label id="endTimeLabel" class="errorMsg">Time must be entered in the format HH:MM AM/PM</label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validateHHMM(value, message) {
    var isValid = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/.test(value);

    if (isValid) {
        document.getElementById(message).style.display = "none";
    }else {
        document.getElementById(message).style.display= "inline";
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dA356/2/)

Answer (score 11):

Change `visible="false"` to `style="visibility:hidden"` on your tags..

---

or better use a class to show/hide the labels..

```
.hidden{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

then on your labels add `class="hidden"`

and with your script remove the class

```
document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").className = 'hidden'; // to hide
```

and

```
document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").className = ''; // to show
```

Answer (score 6):

you could try

```
if (isValid) {
    document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.display = "none";
}else {
    document.getElementById("endTimeLabel").style.display = "block";
}
```

alone those lines

Answer (score 5):

You can set display attribute as none to hide a label.

```
<label id="excel-data-div" style="display: none;"></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get it to hide/show by setting:

```
.style.display = 'none';
.style.display = 'inline';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful that regarding accessibility/screen readers, display:none && visbility:hidden will not be readed. I prefer to set the hidden attribute to true when I don't want the label shown.

For ex:

```
 <label hidden={!showLabel} htmlFor='input-field'>
   {label}
 </label>
```